# (Python) Function to check if a element is the same as the next, returns IndexError when examining the last element

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, enumerate, index-error

I'm trying to make a block of code in Python, to check if an element in a number is the same as the next element. 
The problem is that, when the if statement checks the last element, it can't check if it's the same as the next, since there is no next element.

My code:

```
 for i, elem in enumerate(number):
    if elem == number[i + 1]:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        break

new_num = count + elem + index
```

This returns

```
if elem == number[i + 1]:
IndexError: index out of range
```

Is it better to use a while loop, or can it be fixed with try and except statements? I tried both, but not sure if i used it right.

Comment: My suggestion is to start from the second object and compare it with the previous (if second object does not exists data is empty or has just one element) this solves the "last element" issue

Comment: or iterate till the pre last element.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, elem in enumerate(number):
    if i==0:
     continue; # skip the first element
    if elem == number[i - 1]: # is the element same as previous?
        count = count + 1
    else:
        break

new_num = count + elem + index
```

Comment: No because the first element is read at iteration on i=1 and getting rid of it by slicing will cause "original" number[0] never being evaluated.

Comment: Right, yes. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with indices you can use range() and dont go all the way. What I mean is this:

```
for i in enumerate(len(number) - 1):
    if elem == number[i + 1]:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        break
```

In addition, using a `break` statement considered bad practice, it's better to use this as a condition of a while loop